# what is causing this error :sql incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Whats wrong with the sql syntax below?

```
  /*distinct number of person numbers with D11*/
 select distinct person_number from

 /*select which ones of the 1000 have D11*/
 (select event, person_number
  from table
 where event = 'D11' and person_number in 
 (
 /*top 1000 */
 select distinct top (1000) person_number
  from table with (nolock)
 where client = 3
 ))
```

Comment: when you use a derived table you have to give it an alias

Comment: You should submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias the subquery:

```
/*distinct number of person numbers with D11*/
SELECT DISTINCT person_number
FROM
    /*select which ones of the 1000 have D11*/
    (
    SELECT event
        ,person_number
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE event = 'D11'
        AND person_number IN (
            /*top 1000 */
            SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1000) person_number
            FROM TABLE
            WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE client = 3
            ) a
    ) b
```

duplicate of [Nested select statement in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629979/nested-select-statement-in-sql-server)