# how to get the distinct records based on maximum date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm working with Sql server 2008.i have a table contains following columns,

```
    Id,
    Name,
    Date
```

this table contains more than one record for same id.i want to get distinct id having maximum date.how can i write sql query for this?

Comment: First show us what you have already tried please.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the ROW_[NUMBER() function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and PARTITION BY clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Date FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date desc) AS ROWNUM 
    FROM [MyTable]
) x WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: This helped me as well, thanks. What does the `x` represent before the `WHERE` statement?

Comment: it's an alias for the subquery. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629979/nested-select-statement-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4):

If you need only `ID` column and other columns are NOT required, then you don't need to go with `ROW_NUMBER` or `MAX` or anything else. You just do a `Group By` over `ID` column, because whatever the maximum date is you will get same ID.

```
SELECT ID FROM table GROUP BY ID
--OR
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table
```

If you need `ID` and `Date` columns with maximum date, then simply do a `Group By` on `ID` column and select the `Max` Date.

```
SELECT ID, Max(Date) AS Date
FROM table 
GROUP BY ID
```

If you need all the columns but 1 line having Max. date then you can go with `ROW_NUMBER` or `MAX` as mentioned in other answers.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table AS M
WHERE  Exists(
        SELECT 1
        FROM   table
        WHERE  ID = M.ID
        HAVING M.Date = Max(Date)
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

One way, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
With CTE As
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Date, Rn = Row_Number() Over (Partition By Id
                                                   Order By Date DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT Id --, Name, Date 
FROM CTE
WHERE Rn = 1
```

If multiple max-dates are possible and you want all you could use `DENSE_RANK` instead.

Here's an overview of sql-server's ranking function: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

By the way, `CTE` is a [common-table-expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which is similar to a named sub-query. I'm using it to be able to filter by the `row_number`. This approach allows to select all columns if you want.

Answer (score 1):

> select Max(Date) as "Max Date"
>               from table
>               group by Id 
>               order by Id

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Max(Date)` and `GROUP BY` the other two columns (the ones with repeating data)..

```
SELECT ID, Max(Date) as date, Name
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this

```
DECLARE  @T TABLE(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(50),DATE DATETIME) 
 INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1,'A','2014-04-20'),(1,'A','2014-04-28')
,(2,'A2','2014-04-22'),(2,'A2','2014-04-24')
,(3,'A3','2014-04-20'),(3,'A3','2014-04-28')
,(4,'A4','2014-04-28'),(4,'A4','2014-04-28')
,(5,'A5','2014-04-28'),(5,'A5','2014-04-28')

SELECT T.ID FROM @T T 
WHERE T.DATE=(SELECT MAX(A.DATE) 
              FROM @T A 
              WHERE A.ID=T.ID 
              GROUP BY A.ID ) 
GROUP BY T.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, max(date) from NameOfYourTable group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ROW_NUMBER() function and PARTITION BY clause worked for me thanks!! I needed the End_timestamp for each distinct assetName along with the rest of the records in the row.
This example uses a sql statement in Python.

*Python (DataBricks Notebook)

**sql_statement = '''
SELECT assetName, EngModel, total_cnt, flagged_cnt,diff_EE_avg,flagged_pct,priority,Start_timestamp,End_timestamp FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY assetName ORDER BY End_timestamp desc) AS ROWNUM
FROM ml_dev.ml_prediction_historical
) x WHERE ROWNUM = 1 and End_timestamp BETWEEN current_timestamp() - INTERVAL '36' hours AND current_timestamp()
'''
df_telemetry = spark.sql(sql_statement)
display(df_telemetry)**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1AWS.png)