# Nested select in mysql_query

Tags: mysql

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.guessNum FROM (SELECT * FROM PeerPrediction1 WHERE taskid=$taskid INNER JOIN UserData On username) a WHERE spanflag=0");
```

I have this query but it does not work. PeerPrediction1 is a table
with schema: username, taskid... 
Userdata: username, guessNum,spanfalg
I followed this link, but still something wrong, could anybody help?
[Nested select statement in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629979/nested-select-statement-in-sql-server)

Comment: 'INNER JOIN UserData On username' -- What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss-match inner join on `username`. See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 1):

The query syntax is not correct, and you do not need sub-query for this , you can just use the join to get the data as

```
select
u.guessNum from PeerPrediction1 a
join UserData u on u.username = a.username
where 
a.taskid = ? --- $taskid
and u.spanflag = 0
```