# concatenate years

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        PART ,
        MakeName ,
        ModelName ,
        YearID
FROM    COMPATMATRIX..PART_TABLE
        LEFT JOIN MATRIX_ACES(NOLOCK) ON PART_TABLE.MFGID = MATRIX_ACES.MFGID
                                         AND PART_TABLE.MFG_PART = MATRIX_ACES.MFG_PART
        LEFT JOIN ACES..BASEVEHICLE(NOLOCK) ON MATRIX_ACES.BaseVehicleID = BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
        LEFT JOIN ACES..Make(NOLOCK) ON BaseVehicle.MakeID = Make.MakeID
        LEFT JOIN ACES..Model(NOLOCK) ON BaseVehicle.ModelID = Model.ModelID
WHERE   PART_TABLE.MFGID IN ( 'ACC', 'DRT' )
        AND MakeName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY PART ,
        MakeName ,
        ModelName ,
        YearID
```

I'm try to concatenate all the years in a single row. So there may be multiple Ford F-150's and the only thing that differs is the year and I would like all the years to be in one row instead of having each different year being a new row.

I have tried using GROUP BY but then I have to use an aggregate and that only selects one year. I'm a little stumped. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

sample of what currently happens

```
ACC1234   Ford    F-150   2001
ACC1234   Ford    F-150   2002
ACC1234   Dodge   Ram     2000
```

What I would like

```
ACC1234   Ford    F-150   2001, 2002
ACC1234   Dodge   Ram     2000
```

Comment: Show sample data and an expected result. It can be simplified.

Comment: GROUP BY YearID, ModelName, MakeName ?

Comment: SQL Server... is it STUFF or GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/419956), though impossible to tell without sample data and simplification down to an sscce.

Comment: I think you want to [pivot the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server), but to do that you need to know how many years you'll be looking at, or you have to write dynamic SQL... alternatively, you could use [case statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846007/sql-query-to-pivot-a-column-using-case-when).

Comment: Please stop placing `(NOLOCK)` everywhere. It really isn't a good idea

Comment: To back up what @MarkSinkinson says with some details instead of just an opinion please see this article. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Thanks for the link on the NOLOCK. I'm borrowing this script from someone else as my SQL is pretty weak so I had no idea it was bad behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into STUFF and FOR XML PATH.

http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Taking your code as an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        PART ,
        MakeName ,
        ModelName ,
        STUFF( ( SELECT ',' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), YearID ) FROM ... WHERE ... FOR XML PATH( '' ) ), 1, 1, '' ) AS YearIDs
:
:
ORDER BY PART ,
        MakeName ,
        ModelName
```

Because I don't know what table YearID comes from and don't know the primary keys, I couldn't build the FROM or WHERE clause for you, but I think this will get you on the right path.

Good luck!

Comment: I had to make a few modifications but this put me on the right path. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to something similar, I ended up doing a dynamic SQL, but this was with Oracle (I guess it's possible to do the same in SQL Server based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629979/nested-select-statement-in-sql-server)):

```
SELECT Truckname, 
       SUM(Year2013) Year2013, 
       SUM(Year2014) Year2014, 
       SUM(Year2015) Year2015 
FROM
(
  SELECT Truckname, NULL Year2013, NULL Year2014, COUNT(Field) Year2015
  FROM Trucks
  WHERE Year = '2015'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Truckname, NULL Year2013, COUNT(Field) Year2014, NULL Year2015
  FROM Trucks
  WHERE Year = '2014'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Truckname, COUNT(Field) Year2013, NULL Year2014, NULL Year2015
  FROM Trucks
  WHERE Year = '2013'
) 
GROUP BY Truckname
```

All the "union all selects" of the years are generated dynamically depending how many years you want.
It's probably not the most elegant / optimized solution, but you have one row with the information of all the years. I you want text instead of a counter, you can use MAX instead of count to get the value.

I hope I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve here.