# What is the meaning of the letter 't' in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER by row_id DESC LIMIT 8) t ORDER BY RAND()
```

I saw this in an answer, What does the 't' mean before ORDER BY?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested select statement in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629979/nested-select-statement-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subqueries need an alias name. In this case it is `t`.

With this name you can refer to the result of the subquery and its columns.

Comment: *With this name you can refer to the result of the subquery and its columns.* Also without it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the aliasing even clearer, you should use AS and also use accent grave. This re-written query would be easier to read

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER by `row_id` DESC LIMIT 8) AS `t` ORDER BY RAND()
```